# How to find min and max pixel value of an index?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I tried computing NDVI min and max trying this code but failed.

```
var ndvimin = NDVI.reduce(ee.Reducer.min());
print(ndvimin, 'NDVI min');
```

Help will be aprreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.reduceRegion()` and specifying the region of interest:

```
var NDVI = ee.Image('assetID') // specify the image of interest
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[-98,44], [-96,44], [-96,46], [-98,46], [-98,44]]) // specify your region of interest

var minMaxValues = NDVI.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.minMax(),
                                 geometry: roi 
                                 })

print('minMaxValues', minMaxValues);
```

Comment: Thanks, hooge048! It worked like a charm :)